# How to add a shortcode below add to cart in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to add a shortcode under "Add to cart" button in Woocommerce product pages. This shortcode is displaying a custom field from a plugin. I've tried the code below to output in a product page but it doesn't get outputted:

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'custom_woocommerce_short_description' );

function custom_woocommerce_short_description( $woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item ) {
global $post;

$woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item = $woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item . do_shortcode('[wpuf-meta name="instructions_to_customer"]') ;

return $woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out if anyone needs it:

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'misha_after_add_to_cart_btn' );
 
function misha_after_add_to_cart_btn(){
    echo do_shortcode( '[wpuf-meta name="instructions_to_customer"]' );

}
```